# Signing into Google Accounts with Requests

Tags: python, python-requests, google-account

So I am trying to sign into Google using Python's Request module. After logging in, I am trying to access a google classroom class. However, when I print the content, it seems I am still stuck at the log in page. If anyone could provide some insight on where I am making a mistake, that would help a lot. I am using the following code:

```
import requests

login_url = 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth'
class_url = 'https://classroom.google.com/r/MTQ3NTUxMjk5'

s = requests.session()

#payload = {'Email': 'myemail@gmail.com', 'Passwd': 'mypass'} # This way?
login_data = dict(Email='myemail@gmail.com', Passwd='mypass') # or this way?

s.post(login_url, data=login_data)
r = s.get(class_url)

print r.content
```

I have discovered a new message in the body after some fiddling:

```
 "Oops! Your browser seems to have cookies disabled. Make sure cookies are enabled 
 or try opening a new browser window."
```

Any thoughts?

EDIT:

Within the `page_source`, there is a crazy amount of html, as expected. However, I was looking through it and spotted a `</body>` tag at the end. So I used `find()` to look for the `<body>` tag, but it was not there... Why is the opening body tag not showing up, along with the rest of the content on the page? I have tested with selenium, via Chromedriver and PhantomJS, but only Chromedriver gave me the full html. Why do requests and PhantomJS both hide the content from me?
I also took some screenshots with PhantomJS. [Here is the login page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahJ2O.png) And  [here is after I click submit.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpctU.png) I gave the page ample time to load (10 seconds), so that is not a factor. This is very frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like that

```
a=req.request('GET','http://example.com',headers=head)
cook=a.cookies
a=req.request('POST',page,data=params,headers=head,cookies=cook)
```

Record the cookies given by server then use them. You certainly don't need to `GET` first. Try to login as usual and use a sniffer to track the details. Then *replay* everything your browser sends and how it works with cookies.

Comment: Although this allowed me to load the page, and gain access, for some reason only some of the page data is showing up. That may be because most of it is loaded with Javascript, right?

Comment: @James, but the includes of JS show? Then you can use something like the WebKit webbrowser of [QT](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-demos-declarative-webbrowser-example.html) or PyQT to render the page.

Comment: Hmmm. I have found something very interesting. In the huge chunk of html (the page source) that I have, I had said above that JS might be keeping it from loading. However, there is a "</body>" tag in the html, but there is no "<body>" tag. How/why is google hiding whats in the body? See my edit on my question for further explanation.